# DMA between GPIO and SRAM on STM32

Tags: sram, dma, stm32f3

Here I am trying to move the data at the `SRAM` location `0x20000010` into the `ODR` register of the `GPIOE` of `STM32f303`. But it is not happening for me(I an not see the data change in the ODR while debugging) . I dont understand why. Can any one help me out in this?

**EDIT**

```
int SRAM_ADDRESS __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x20000010")));  
volatile Task_S_T *Task;
    Task = LCD_FIFO_Peek();

    SRAM_ADDRESS = Task->Data;

        //initialize source and destination arrays
    uint32_t source = 0x20000010;                               // SRAM Starting address where the LCD Task data is loaded
    uint32_t destination = 0x48001014;
  DMA_InitTypeDef   DMA_InitStructure;

  /* Enable DMA1 clock -------------------------------------------------------*/
  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);

  DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel1);

  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr =    (uint32_t)destination;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)source;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 16;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Enable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
  DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel1, &DMA_InitStructure);

  DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel1, ENABLE);
  LCD_Port_Set_Output();    // Just ensure that the LCD port is in output direction on the appropriate pin masks.
  GPIO_SetBits(LCD_BUS_GPIO_PORT, LCD_E_PIN);                   // Toggle Enable pin on.
  GPIO_ResetBits(LCD_BUS_GPIO_PORT, LCD_E_PIN);                 // Toggle Enable pin off.
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You've defined your data arrays as holding 32 bit words, which won't fit in an 8 bit IO port - and the IO port will only hold one 8-bit byte at a time.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the normal function (please see edit section) using DMA.

Comment: @spp: How do you locate your data at address 0x20000000? I think you should first put your data int a array, just like "uint32_t source[SIZE]", and then set this to the source address, look if it work well. If all works as you expected, then try put the data in absolute address.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? If is ARM MDK, then if you want to put data in a absolute address, you do need some **tricks**, have you see this link: http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2829.htm?

Comment: @diverger: You are right and that's how I have put the data in the absolute address just like that only and I verified that using keil's feature to look in to the particular memory address.

Comment: @spp: If you are using ARM MDK, try this: __align(4) uint8_t src[16]; Then put some data in it, or copy from your "Task->Data", see if the GPIO output are right. You reference a absolute address using pointer, but that address maybe used by ARM MDK, so your data maybe over write or you may over write ARM MDK's data, i suggest you use __attribute__((at(address))) keyword.

Comment: linker is giving me error for using this key word

Comment: Are you using GCC compiler?

Comment: I was debugging it ...once the write instruction executes my debugger show the message Can not access memory and it goes in to the Hardfault handler loop.

Comment: __align(4), is a memory alignment instruction on ARM MDK compiler. If you are using GCC equivalent __attribute__ ((aligned (4))). Did you try " __align(4) uint8_t src[16];"?

Comment: The is issue not related to the allocation memory at the absolute address seems its been resolved by `int SRAM_ADDRESS __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x20000010")));  `. Now the problem is DMA is enabling but data trasnfer in the ODR is not taking place. I can see the desired data into the SRAM memory location.

Comment: Which GPIO and DMA channel are you using?

Comment: GPIOE and DMA1 Channel 1

Comment: How many data are you want to write to SRAM_ADDRESS?

Comment: 16 bits for now

Comment: i want to write into GPIOE->ODR

Comment: Try "DMA_M2M" this will be software "trigger" of the DMA. That is when you complete your DMA setup, then use "DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel1, ENABLE);", the DMA will start transfer. I think your problem is you are using "DMS_M2M_Disable" but you have not given it a "trigger" source, so the transfer won't fire.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: yes its working..need to enable DMA M2M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am a bit stuck in that because do not have much knowledge on SRAM
>   and how to access it. can anyone help me out here?

"SRAM" just like the memory on your PC, all your function stacks, and auto variables are located in it. In your code above, the two arrays:

> uint32_t source[SIZE]; uint32_t destination[SIZE];

just are allocated in "SRAM", the code your posted, is using DMA to transfer data from array "source" to "destination", and when done, it generate a interrupt.

So, what your need is just locating your data in SRAM, then fire the DMA. If your data need be located at a **given** address such as "0x??????", the address need be in your SRAM's address. For STM32f303VCT6, the interanl SRAM starts from address 0x20000000, ends on 0x2000A000.

There may be different methods depend on which compiler you are using. For ARM MDK, you can go here: http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2829.htm

---

**Update:**

If you want to use DMA to transfer data/command from your memory to LCD. You may need:

1. Put your data/command in the fixed memory location. And you may need to set your LCD control pins, such as A0, enable, etc....
2. Set the "DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr" to "&GPIOX->ODR", "X" dependent on which GPIO port you are using.
3. Set "DMA_DIR" to "DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST";
4. Set "DMA_MemoryBaseAddr" to your data address.
5. Set the "DMA_BufferSize" to your buffer size. Note:

> Specifies the buffer size, in data unit, of the specified Channel. The
>   data unit is equal to the configuration set in DMA_PeripheralDataSize
>   or DMA_MemoryDataSize members depending in the transfer direction.

6. Set "DMA_PeripheralDataSize" and "DMA_MemoryDataSize" to byte, because your LCD interface is 8 bit.
7. When using "DMA_M2M_Disable", you need a hardware DMA trigger source, using "DMA_M2M" you can trig the DMA by your code, when you enable the DMA, the transfer starts.
8. Finally, enable DMA and fire it.

Comment: Um, you want use DMA to transfer data from SRAM to LCD, right?

Comment: yes..correct!!!